# What is redux and what problem does it solve?

Tags: redux

When I searched for Redux most of the time I get the answer

> Redux is a predictable state container for JavaScript and comes as an
>   external library which can be used together with front-end frameworks
>   like React, Angular, Ember.js, Backbone, etc.

I did not get the definition actually. What does it mean by **predictable state container **?

And as a new tool, it should solve some problems with web development. So, what redux does and how it facilitates us?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think when someone says that Redux is a predictable state container it means that redux has a very strict way how to change the data, sometimes called unidirectional data flow.

I mostly used it in React application, so I can tell which problem it solves in this case. While your application is small, you probably will not see the reason to use Redux, but when it grows, when you have lots of components which use the same data and have to communicate with each other, it becomes really painful to store all state somewhere in the root components and pass it through all the children. There may be performance issues as well, all components between a root one a chield which needs some part of your state will be re-rendered.

So using Redux easily connect your components and select those parts of the state which they need. Also, communication between components becomes much easier, instead of passing callbacks to props, your components just listed to state and represent it, any time you need to change a state just send an action.

Regarding predictable state management, Redux is some kind of event sourcing, instead of changing a state directly, so send actions (events) which describe how to modify the state and reducer applies these changes.

There are way more things to say about Redux, at least middlewares, if you are familiar with Rx, you can try to use redux-observable which are really powerful, you can listen to some actions or a state changes to combine it with others. I recommend you to take a look at [redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/) and some [article like this](https://code-cartoons.com/a-cartoon-intro-to-redux-3afb775501a6), I believe you will find an answer to your question.

Comment: Basically, redux allow you to save data into a "store" which can be accessed by all of your components

Comment: @fctmolina this sounds like a global dictionary of key-value pairs. Why people even bothered to minimize the scope of variables they can see at every moment

Comment: It's predictable because the state can't be changed willy-nilly. It can only be changed as a result of an action. That's one of the aspects of it that I like about it. It also allows me to arrange my store into different stores. So for example I have the following stores: user, application, document, changes... I know what I'll find in each one at any given time. When I need to update something about the user, I know I'll need to do it in the user reducer. I know that the information will be in the user store.

Comment: @SergeyVoytovich Minimising the scope of variables saves memory and protects the data. The data will only be accessed and modified by functions that needs to perform operations using that variable not just by any function. It also makes the code more readable